# PowerShell reading sorting data

Tags: powershell

I have a question: I want to store data in a variable with three columns and then process it. So I looked at an example with hash tables, which seemed great but then I need three columns, and I want to be able to run queries against this with it having say 100 rows.

What's the best way of doing this?

Example

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom objects, each with three properties.  That will give you the three column output.  If you have V3 you can create custom objects using a hashtable like so:

```
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{Name='John';Age=42;Hobby='Music'}
PS> $obj | ft -auto

Name Age Hobby
---- --- -----
John  42 Music
```

If you are on V2 you can create these objects with `New-Object`:

```
$obj = new-object psobject -Property @{Name='John';Age=42;Hobby='Music'}
```

Comment: If you have v2 or v1, you can still create an object to do it, it just requires a little more work.  You'll need to look at New-PSObject and Add-Member to replace that first line.

Comment: @HunterEidson Sure. But are folks really still hanging onto V2?  Folks, move to v3 at the very least.  ;-)  That said, I updated my answer to show how to do this in V2.

Answer (score 2):

I would create an array or collection  of custom PS Objects, each having 3 properties, then use the Powershell comparison operators on that array/collection to do my queries.

see:

```
Get-Help about_object_creation
Get-Help about_comparison_operators
Get-Help Where-Object
```